# Do I need to apply for a new Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a visa valid from 21-05-18 to 17-06-18, type C, multiple-entry, duration of stay (13 days).

I want to go to France in July. Do I have to apply for another Schengen visa?

Comment: Well, if your visa expires in June...

Comment: Why do you ask the question? The visa validity period seems very clear.

Answer (score 1):

How long you've been in the Schengen Area doesn't affect the validity of the visa (thinking so is the only reason I can see for asking the question), so yes, in july your current visa won't be valid, so you'll have to apply for another.

Comment: "How long you've been in the Schengen Area doesn't affect the validity of the visa": That's true, but it does affect whether and when and for how long one can return, because of the 90/180 rule.